# Amazon S3 Permissions

Tags: mobile, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using temporary sessions in Amazon S3 with GetSessionToken/GetFederationToken, I am planing on having more than 10K users each one can upload to S3 so initialy I thought of use a bucket for each user and set write (upload) permissions per bucket for each user, but since there is a limitation on the number of buckets per Amazon account I have forsaken that idea.

How can I set a permission like allow public read, and upload only if the prefix on the key of the object that the user wants to upload ?

For example if username X uploads a file the key must be like X_filename.

Or any other way which allows me to have security, this is for a mobile app and I would not like to go through our own servers when uploading a file.

Edit:

I've tried the operation GetFederationToken with the following policy

```
"{
   "Statement":[{
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action":["s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion",
      "s3:DeleteObject",\"s3:DeleteObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::user.uploads/john/*"
   }
   ]
}"
```

I have the bucket user.uploads on S3 and folder john

however any upload with the session credentials to bucket user.uploads with key john/filename fails with access denied"

Comment: This will work, but you need to check everything. For instance the policy may be wrong. - Make a wide open one for internal testing, then narrow it. Also all calls to amazon S3 from iOS need to use the federated token that you got back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Amazon's Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/) service is what you need. The [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingIAMPolicies.html) has numerous examples, some of which match your scenario.

From the docs:

> **Example 5**: Allow a partner to drop files into a specific portion of
>   the corporate bucket
>
> In this example, we create a group called WidgetCo that represents the
>   partner company, then create a user for the specific person (or
>   application) at the partner company who needs access, and then put the
>   user in the group.
>
> We then attach a policy that gives the group PutObject access to the
>   following directory in the corporate bucket:
>   my_corporate_bucket/uploads/widgetco.
>
> We also want to prevent the WidgetCo group from doing anything else
>   with the bucket, so we add a statement that denies permission to any
>   Amazon S3 actions except PutObject on any Amazon S3 resource in the
>   AWS account. This is only necessary if there's a broad policy in use
>   elsewhere in your AWS account that gives users wide access to Amazon
>   S3.
>
> ```
> {
>     "Statement":[{
>         "Effect":"Allow",
>         "Action":"s3:PutObject",
>         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my_corporate_bucket/uploads/widgetco/*"
>     },
>     {
>         "Effect":"Deny",
>         "NotAction":"s3:PutObject",
>         "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my_corporate_bucket/uploads/widgetco/*"]
>     },
>     {
>         "Effect":"Deny",
>         "Action":"s3:*",
>         "NotResource": ”arn:aws:s3:::my_corporate_bucket/uploads/widgetco/*"
>     }]
> }
> ```

You would create a new identity for each user and use that to control access to the subfolders (prefixes) as needed.

Comment: Yes but im not using groups neither AWS users im using Federated users managed outside of AWS\

Comment: A federated user can use the same policy doc as any user. But the policy doc needs to be small - the above example may work for federated, I have not tried it. So you make a customized policy doc for each user. Note that you should use the official AWS iOS sdk - it supports session tokens.